# Incorrect time inf Google Calendar event from imported URL

Tags: url, time, import, hyperlink, google-calendar-api

help me please generate correct URL for adding event to Google Calendar.
Link should add event for time 19:00 - 21:00, but Google sets incorrect time 21:00 - 23:00.

I can't understand why, i've tried to pass timezone, but the same result.

Example:
[https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some+details&location=kiev+khreschatyk+1&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000Z/20161130T210000Z](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some%20details&location=kiev%20khreschatyk%201&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000Z/20161130T210000Z)

http://prnt.sc/cro92n

With timezone:
[https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some+details&location=kiev+khreschatyk+1&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000Z/20161130T210000Z&ctz=Europe/Kiev](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some%20details&location=kiev%20khreschatyk%201&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000Z/20161130T210000Z&ctz=Europe/Kiev)

http://prnt.sc/cro9y0

Thanks!

Comment: time will probably be the timezone of the calendar in question.   I have never heard of hacking render like that.   Really this should be done though the Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 0):

it needs just remove 'Z' from dates - for set local time (because 'Z' means time in GMT)

so, this works:

[https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some+details&location=kiev+khreschatyk+1&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000/20161130T210000](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some%20details&location=kiev%20khreschatyk%201&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000/20161130T210000)

[https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some+details&location=kiev+khreschatyk+1&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000/20161130T210000&ctz=Europe/Kiev](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=TestEvent&details=some%20details&location=kiev%20khreschatyk%201&sf=true&output=xml&dates=20161130T190000/20161130T210000&ctz=Europe/Kiev)